# I want to keep the pop-up window not closed

Tags: c#

The form closes when an event is performed in a pop-up window.

I hope that the event will be held in the pop-up window without being closed.

```
if (class1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Yes){

   //dialog not closed

   if (class1.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK) {  

     //dialog closed

   } 
}
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. What do you mean the form closes when "an event is performed"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible. Once `ShowDialog` is executed, the form is closed and disposed. You can't revive it any more.

The only solution is not to close the form. I guess you have a call to `Form.Close()` or you have set the `AcceptButton` property on the form.

From the form, before closing, you could cancel it, but I guess you have a broader design issue. Since `ShowDialog` won't return until the form is closed, you might need to use `Show`.

Comment: Closed yes, but disposed no. You can still use the form instance to access public properties of the form instance.

Comment: If those properties don't call disposed members, yes. So `form.TextBox1.Text` will fail.